# How to display a image use GTK3's GtkGlArea on win32 platform

Tags: c++, windows, gtk, gtk3, glfw

**Operation System**:   windows 11

**BuildEnv**:           msys2 + mingw32

**GTK Version**:        3.24.33

I use GTK3's GtkGLArea widget to display a image on win32 platform, but it didn't work, the window's background color is changed,but image not display, code as follow:

```c
static gboolean render(GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context)
{
    //work, background color changed
    glClearColor (0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    cairo_surface_t* surface = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("./test.PNG");
    unsigned char* data= cairo_image_surface_get_data(surface);
    
    //not work
    glRasterPos2f(-1,1);
    glPixelZoom( 1, -1 );
    glDrawPixels(
            cairo_image_surface_get_width(surface),
            cairo_image_surface_get_height(surface),
            GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);

    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);

    return TRUE;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget* window;
    GtkWidget* gl_area;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "picplayer-gl");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1920, 1080);

    gl_area = gtk_gl_area_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),gl_area);

    g_signal_connect(gl_area,"render",G_CALLBACK(render),NULL);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk3.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return status;
}
```

When i use glfw instead of gtk3, the codes work well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd like to help you out, but it's hard to assist when we don't know _what_ is going wrong with the code. Please [edit] your question to contain descriptions of any specific problems/errors your code has, making sure to include full error messages if any. Read the [help], and [ask] in particular, for more information on how to ask a good question. Read the [tour] for a basic introduction to how things are run here.

Comment: The answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153819/how-to-load-and-display-an-image-in-opengl-es-3-0-using-c