# How do I set OpenGL version for GtkGLArea in Python GTK?

Tags: python, opengl, pygtk, pygobject

I have this class below that works in Windows using OpenGL 3.0. However, in Linux this fails because it appears to be using an OpenGL 2.0 methods on an OpenGL 4.6 context. I get this error. How do tell the GtkGLArea in Python GTK to use OpenGL 4.6 libraries?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/git/DisplayIn/src/displayin/engine/openglrenderer.py", line 190, in render
    self.setupGraphics()
  File "/home/user/git/DisplayIn/src/displayin/engine/openglrenderer.py", line 120, in setupGraphics
    self.initBuffers()
  File "/home/user/git/DisplayIn/src/displayin/engine/openglrenderer.py", line 133, in initBuffers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), ctypes.c_void_p(0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenGL/latebind.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.wrapperFunction( self.baseFunction, *args, **named )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenGL/GL/VERSION/GL_2_0.py", line 469, in glVertexAttribPointer
    contextdata.setValue( key, array )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenGL/contextdata.py", line 58, in setValue
    context = getContext( context )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/OpenGL/contextdata.py", line 40, in getContext
    raise error.Error(
OpenGL.error.Error: Attempt to retrieve context when no valid context
```

This is the code of the class

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from OpenGL.GL import *
import numpy as np
import gc

VERTEX_SOURCE = '''
#version 330
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;
layout (location=1) in vec3 color;
layout (location=2) in vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(position,1.0);
ourColor = color;
TexCoord= vec2(texCoord.x,1.0-texCoord.y);
}'''

FRAGMENT_SOURCE ='''
#version 330
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
void main(){
color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
};'''

recVertices = np.array([
    # Positions           Colors           Texture Coords
    1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,    1.0, 1.0,   # Top Right    0
    1.0, -1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,    1.0, 0.0,   # Bottom Right 1
    -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   # Bottom Left  2
    -1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0,   # Top Left     3
    1.0,  1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,    1.0, 1.0,   # Top Right    4
], dtype=np.float32)

def checkGlError(op: str):
    error = glGetError()
    if error is not None and error != 0:
        print("after %s() glError (0x%x)", op, error)

# Based on examples:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153819/how-to-load-and-display-an-image-in-opengl-es-3-0-using-c
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565884/use-of-the-gtk-glarea-in-pygobject-gtk3
class OpenGLRenderer(Gtk.GLArea):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.GLArea.__init__(self)
        self.connect("realize", self.onRealize)
        self.connect("render", self.onRender)
        self.ctx = None
        self.frame = self.createBlankScreenFrame()
        self.area = None
        self.shaderProgram = None
        self.positionHandle = None
        self.textureId = None
        self.vao = None
        self.vbos = None
        self.version = None

    def getVersion(self):
        major = glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION)
        minor = glGetIntegerv(GL_MINOR_VERSION)
        version = glGetString(GL_VERSION)

        return major, minor, version
    
    def createBlankScreenFrame(self):
        frame = np.array([[[0, 0, 0]]], dtype=np.uint8)
        return frame

    def onRealize(self, area):

        error = area.get_error()
        if error != None:
            print("your graphics card is probably too old : ", error)
        else:
            print(area, "realize... fine so far")

        self.ctx = self.get_context()
        self.ctx.make_current()

        major, minor, self.version = self.getVersion()
        print("OpenGL realized", self.ctx)
        print("%s\n", self.version)

    def onRender(self, area, ctx):
        
        # Render will be invoked separately
        # self.render(self.frame)
        return True

    def setupGraphics(self):

        if self.shaderProgram is None:
            # Load Shaders, Create program, Setup Graphics
            vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
            glShaderSource(vertexShader, VERTEX_SOURCE)
            glCompileShader(vertexShader)
            status = glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
            print("Compile vertexShader status: " + str(status == GL_TRUE))

            pixelShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            glShaderSource(pixelShader, FRAGMENT_SOURCE)
            glCompileShader(pixelShader)
            status = glGetShaderiv(pixelShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS)
            print("Compile vertexShader status: " + str(status == GL_TRUE))

            self.shaderProgram = glCreateProgram()
            glAttachShader(self.shaderProgram, vertexShader)
            glAttachShader(self.shaderProgram, pixelShader)
            glLinkProgram(self.shaderProgram)
            glBindFragDataLocation(self.shaderProgram, 0, "color")
            self.positionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(self.shaderProgram, "position")

            # Initalize Vertex Buffers
            self.initBuffers()
    
    def initBuffers(self):
        # Initialize an buffer to store all the verticles and transfer them to the GPU
        self.vao = glGenVertexArrays(1) # Generate VAO
        self.vbos = glGenBuffers(1) # Generate VBO
        glBindVertexArray(self.vao) # Bind the Vertex Array

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbos) # Bind verticles array for OpenGL to use
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * len(recVertices), recVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
        
        # 1. set the vertex attributes pointers
        # Position Attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), ctypes.c_void_p(0))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        # Color Attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), ctypes.c_void_p(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        # Texture Coordinate Attribute
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(GLfloat), ctypes.c_void_p(6 * sizeof(GLfloat)))
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        glBindVertexArray(0) # 3. Unbind VAO
    
    def generateTexture(self, frame):

        # Delete previous frame
        # del self.frame
        # gc.collect()

        # Update Frame
        self.frame = frame

        # Delete previous textures to avoid memory leak
        if self.textureId is not None:
            glDeleteTextures(1, [self.textureId])

        # If we have a frame to display
        if frame is not None:
            # extract array from Image
            h, w, d = frame.shape

            # Frame is a 3 dimentional array where shape eg. (1920, 1080, 3)
            # Where it is w, h, and 3 values for color
            # https://www.educba.com/numpy-flatten/
            pixels = frame.ravel(order = 'C')

            # Generate Texture
            self.textureId = glGenTextures(1)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textureId) # Bind our 2D texture so that following set up will be applied

            # Set texture wrapping parameter
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

            # Set texture Filtering parameter
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)

            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels)
            glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) # Unbind 2D textures

    def render(self, frame):

        # Set OpenGL Render Context
        if self.ctx is not None and frame is not None:
            self.ctx.make_current()

            # Initialize Graphics
            self.setupGraphics()

            # Generate Texture
            self.generateTexture(frame)

            # Clear Screen
            glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            # Use Shader Program, Bind Vertex Array and Texture
            glUseProgram(self.shaderProgram)
            checkGlError("glUseProgram")
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)
            checkGlError("glActiveTexture")
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textureId)
            checkGlError("glBindTexture")
            mlocation = glGetUniformLocation(self.shaderProgram, "ourTexture")
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation")
            glUniform1i(mlocation, 0)
            checkGlError("glUniform1i")
            glBindVertexArray(self.vao)
            checkGlError("glBindVertexArray")

            # Render Frame
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 2, 3)
            
            # Queue Draw
            glFlush()
            self.queue_draw()
```

Any ideas on how to set the OpenGL version for GtkGLArea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, I got this error because I was using the app in Wayland. This code runs fine in X11 so I needed to add this code to be run sometime before the code above to make this app work in Wayland as well.

```
# Needed for Wayland Support for OpenGL in Linux
if 'WAYLAND_DISPLAY' in os.environ and 'PYOPENGL_PLATFORM' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['PYOPENGL_PLATFORM'] = 'x11'
```